# Using parse.com to receive Trello webhooks

Tags: parse-platform, webhooks, trello

### 1. Goal

I want to use parse.com to receive Trello webhook.

**1a. Why?:** Because I want to monitor my trello model and receive say a push notification on my android device and do neat things from the push notficiation (I'm an Android Dev)

### 2. What I've tried

#### 2a. Setup on parse.com

1. I've created an app on parse.com
2. Obtained the keys (REST keys for the REST api)
3. Checked the above endpoint with Postman, works perfectly.

#### 2b. Setup on trello.com

4. I've obtained an api appkey and secret; with full write on all boards, never expires
5. Tested the above with Postman, works perfectly fine.
6. PROBLEM: Posted to the following using Postman (of course with proper details for key, token, model, etc.

Request=

```
$.post("https://trello.com/1/tokens/[USER_TOKEN]/webhooks/?key=[APPLICATION_KEY]", {
  description: "My first webhook",
  callbackURL: "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/webhookReceiverTrello",
  idModel: "4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c",
});
```

Response Try=

```
URL (https://api.parse.com/1/functions/webhookReceiverTrello) did not return 200 status code, got 401
```

### 3. What is the problem?

Parse.com expects auth keys, etc as header. AFAIK Trello can NOT DO that.

How do I get a trello webhook to call a parse.com cloud function ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user3344977 oh yes, I just wrote my own proxy (just receive the webhook and make the proper post request to parse)

Answer (score 0):

## Use a proxy (a simple web app will do)

This is how I did it:

Receive the webhook on a simple web app and make the necessary post call to parse.com

- I used heroku for hosting
- I used [MeteorJS](http://meteor.com) for the web app

> **Note:** An issue you could encounter:
>
> - Trello.com sends calls to webhooks in proper order i.e. a card was created, the same card was updated, etc.
> - When you receive the webhook and make (proper) post calls, they will be received out of order at parse.com i.e. a card was updated and then it was created. This is just due to the way internet works, if you need an explanation, it's another `SO` question. ;)
>
> This took me a while to figure out; mentioning so that you don't also spend your time with this.
>
> **A Fix:** I don't know a simple/efficient way to fix this. Please let me know if you do. One possible solution is to queue all `POST` calls i.e. make `POST call 1` and when a successful callback is gotten do the next one. Trello.com seems to do this in a more quicker fashion, it doesn't seem like they wait for a callback given how quick successive calls are received.